# add GLKViewController to subview - GLKView context causes crash

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, glkit, glkview

I have a pretty simple set up in mind, having a mainViewController that has a GLKViewController on top of it. The idea is having my GLKViewController in a box, that take sup 1/3 of the screen, on the mainViewController. This can be seen below:

[image]

That white box is my own custom GLKViewController with the follow code:

*boxViewController.h*

```
//boxViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface boxViewController : GLKViewController
@end
```

*boxViewController.m*

```
//boxViewController.m
#import "boxViewController.m"

@interface boxViewController () { }
@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;
@end

@implementation boxViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
//    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
}

@end
```

On my `mainViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` I simply call boxViewController like this:

```
boxViewController* box = [[boxChartViewController alloc] init];
box.view.layer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height/3);
[self.view addSubview:box.view];
```

which works perfect.

Notice that in my boxViewController.m I had `view.context = self.context` commented out. If you uncomment it, my application crashes without any error messaging (it breaks with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the `objc_msgSend` assembly code [line 8 to be specific]).

What am I doing incorrectly that when I set the context the application crashes? From all the tutorials I noticed that they have the same set up, except not setting the controller on another controller. Though I don't understand why GLKViewController couldn't be framed on another controller, so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours of messing around I found that adding the viewController as a child works:

```
#import "mainViewController.h"

@implementation mainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0f/255.0f green:242.0f/255.0f blue:242.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    boxViewController* chart = [[boxViewController alloc] init];
    chart.view.layer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height/3);
    chart.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    chart.view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    [self addChildViewController:chart];
    [self.view addSubview:chart.view];


}
```

Comment: I have the same issue trying to add the AdBannerView as a child of the view. Not sure if the ad banner is designed to work with a controller. It clearly seems like GLKView is not happy with having child views without a controller. I can't find much info on the exact problem here. Were you able to get more info on this?

Comment: Hey @Shammi, I'm unsure how it will work with the integration AdBannerView and GLKView. You might want to ask a question about it so others can help.